# Running dockerd gives error "open //./pipe/docker_engine: Access is denied." (Windows Server 1709)

Tags: windows, powershell, docker

I am following the instructions on how to get Linux Containers working for Windows Server 1709, that have been provided on these two websites: https://github.com/linuxkit/lcow, https://gist.github.com/rn/6bfade1ba98e22691cb287cc8c23609b

When I get to the dockerd command that is required, I get the following error from the powershell terminal:
`open //./pipe/docker_engine: Access is denied.`

I searched around and the closet result returned me a stackoverflow page found here: [Docker for Windows 10 //./pipe/docker_engine: access is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40078969/docker-for-windows-10-pipe-docker-engine-access-is-denied)

The question and answer is unrelated to what is happening in my situation. Does anyone have any ideas as to why this error is occurring? I am running Powershell as Admin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Docker service (running as a Windows service) is bound to the dockerd application (because dockerd is the docker daemon). If you stop the Docker service and then run the dockerd command from the sites listed in the question, it will work.

It is worth noting that running this dockerd command holds up the terminal. This is because the docker service is now running from that docker daemon command that you have just provided.

If you are happy with the way docker is performing now, my suggestion would be to remove the current Docker service and replace it with the dockerd command options that you have provided.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the user running docker is part of docker_users group

I run Docker remotely as a non admin user.

1. For this the user running docker should have full permission to
   location where Docker is installed.
2. User should be part of docker-users group
3. docker daemon runs on port 2375 by default. Try to whitelist this
   port. Allow incoming connections to 2375 in Windows Firewall
   settings
4. Restart your docker daemon and Docker service.

Refer link below , to understand docker-users group
https://icij.gitbook.io/datashare/faq-errors/you-are-not-allowed-to-use-docker-you-must-be-in-the-docker-users-group-.-what-should-i-do

Restart the running Docker instance[Docker for Windows] if required. You do not have to reinstall.

Comment: the URL has changed, it is now:  https://icij.gitbook.io/datashare/usage/faq/common-errors/you-are-not-allowed-to-use-docker-you-must-be-in-the-docker-users-group-.-what-should-i-do