# I've installed Docker on Windows 2019 Server, but I can only interact with it from an administrative shell

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop, windows-server-2019, windows-container

I've been following [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/deploy-containers-on-server) to get Docker installed on a brand new Windows 2019 Server.

As long as I use an administrative account, I can login and run whatever I want:

```
C:\Windows\system32>docker run hello-world

Hello from Docker!
This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.
```

But if I try to run the same command from a non-administrator shell I get this error message:

> C:\Users\sysUKNG>docker run helloworld docker: error during connect:
> Post http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.40/containers/create:
> open //./pipe/docker_engine: Access is denied. In the default daemon
> configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to
> connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not
> running. See 'docker run --help'.

Is Microsoft expecting Docker users to only interact with the Docker Daemon from an elevated account? I guess this kind of makes sense if you assume that the purpose of Docker is to run long-lasting servers. It's logical that you'd want only an administrator to be able to start and stop these kinds of things.

However, I'm trying to run a large number of batch processes which get triggered by a scheduler run from a non-administrative service account. I really don't want my scheduler to have to run elevated.

In Docker for Linux I can make any user I want to have access to to Docker part of the "docker-users" group. Does Windows have an equivalent way to allow any user to have this kind of access? My server has no group with a similar name, but I do have "Hyper-V Administrators", which it says gives the account "Complete and unrestricted access", which is not exactly what I want.

Ideally I want a certain group of users to be able to start and stop a process that runs on Docker for Windows inside a Windows container.

[This page suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40078969/docker-for-windows-10-pipe-docker-engine-access-is-denied) that the solution has something to do with opening a TCP port, but I'm using the Windows Server version of Docker. It doesn't have the same control panel that you normally get with Docker Desktop for Windows.

[Another page suggests](https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/byrsy1/run_docker_enterprise_on_windows_server_2016_as/) that I can only run Docker commands from an elevated shell? I too want to run some Docker stuff from Jenkins jobs.

Answer (score 3):

create a group "docker-users". Needs to be run after each reboot.

```
$account="MY-SERVER-NAME\docker-users"
$npipe = "\\.\pipe\docker_engine"
$dInfo = New-Object "System.IO.DirectoryInfo" -ArgumentList $npipe
$dSec = $dInfo.GetAccessControl()
$fullControl =[System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::FullControl
$allow =[System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow
$rule = New-Object "System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule" -ArgumentList $account,$fullControl,$allow
$dSec.AddAccessRule($rule)
$dInfo.SetAccessControl($dSec)
```

I think I grabbed this idea from here : https://dille.name/blog/2017/11/29/using-the-docker-named-pipe-as-a-non-admin-for-windowscontainers/